# Flutter: change showAboutDialog style

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

This is my code:

```
showAboutDialog(
                  context: context,
                  applicationName: translate('title'),
                  applicationVersion: packageInfo.version,
                  children: [
                    const Image(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/icon_number.png'),
                      height: 150,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
```

The version here is not really visible:

[image]

But the problems come when I check the licenses:
[image]

AppBar is not visible at all.

This is my theme:

```
theme: ThemeData(
              appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
                foregroundColor: Helpers().colors['text'], // AppBar text
              ),
              textTheme: TextTheme(
```

bodyLarge: TextStyle(color: Helpers().colors['text']),
bodyMedium: TextStyle(color: Helpers().colors['text']),
bodySmall: TextStyle(color: Helpers().colors['text']),
),
primaryColor: Helpers().colors['text'],
colorScheme:
ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Helpers().colors['text']),
scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
useMaterial3: true,
fontFamily: 'GochiHand-Regular',
),

...

```
final Map colors = {
    'background': Helpers.hexToColor('#001a29'),
    'text': Helpers.hexToColor('#ffffff'),
    'secondary': Helpers.hexToColor('#FF9B8F'),
    'buttonBg': Helpers.hexToColor('#fa3542')
  };
```

Comment: Which app bar are you hoping to show on the license page or widget, plus can you provide more on the license page or widget

Comment: Second image on top of TimeTap. I can't provide more, that's the Flutter method. If I had the code I could change its color directly